# NAType object is not callable error - summing a float

Tags: python

beginner here, hoping for some help.

I've got a large dataset with range of Int and Float fields, several containing NaN values.

When initially imported from csv, series was categorised as an object, so converted to a float using this:

```
    data['bu'] = pd.to_numeric(data['bu'], errors='coerce').astype('float')
```

Now and looking to fill the NaN values with mean. Trying this code:

```
    num_bu = data['bu'].dropna()
    mean_bu = sum(num_bu) / len(num_bu)
```

And I get this error:

---

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
5 #num_bu
6
----> 7 mean_bu = sum(num_bu) / len(num_bu)
8
9 mean_bu

TypeError: 'NAType' object is not callable

I thought the dropna would fix this, but I'm stumped. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

---

Follow on edit... not sure if this is where my problem is.
Noticing the data type is:

pandas.core.series.Series

Have tried this code to change to an Int or Float (depending on the column):

```
    data["age"]= data["age"].astype('Int64')
```

when I check type after this though, still saying it is:
pandas.core.series.Series

weird though as when I check dtypes on the dataframe the types all look correct (all correctly Int or Float)

No idea what I'm doing wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

All good.... changed to Series functions and worked.